# Navigation stack will not be updated, segue from GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm having issue with segue to the existing `UIViewcontroller` via the pushViewController.

When I'm tap on the place in resultsViewController, I expect the segue to the MainVC, but i have an error:

**pushViewController:animated: called on  while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.**

How can I fix this, and have the transition to MainVC??

Comment: Where is `SearchVC` in the hierarchy? Is it the root of the Navigation VC? Was it pushed onto the Nav Stack? Was it "presented"? Do you have actual **segues** defined in your Storyboard? If so, is it possible you are triggering a segue *and* calling `.pushViewController` at the same time?

Comment: Please check the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/vcNVU. It's a hierarchy with actual segues defined in the Storyboard. SearchVC was presented programmatically from MainVC: `let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil), 
        let searchVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchVC") as! SearchVC, self.navigationController?.pushViewController(searchVC, animated: false)` and this transition works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

1. Make sure you are not "doubling up" on navigation. If you use a **Segue** to transition to another view controller, do not *also* call `.pushViewController()` or `present()`.
2. Understand the difference between **push** and **present**.

In your case, it appears (based on your description and your screenshot) that `MainVC` is the root VC of your NavController, and a Segue has *pushed* `SearchVC` onto the navigation stack. If `SearchVC` "slides in from the right" that is almost certainly the case.

If you have **pushed** a VC onto the Nav Stack, then you want to **pop** it off the stack with `popViewController(animated: Bool)`. That will "slide the previous VC back in from the left".

In your `goToVc()` function, you are creating a **new** instance of `MainVC` and trying to push it onto the stack.